# When importing PHP files into an HTML document, how do I prevent the Meta and Title tags from injecting?

Tags: php, html, include

In the  tags of my php document, I removed the Title and Meta tags, therefore the header is empty, as such:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require '/DBConnect.php';
//More code here that generates my output.
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I view the site and inspect element, the resultant injected code includes a Title tag and a meta tag as such:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
//Resultant Code From the import.
```

Does anyone know how to prevent these tags from injecting? (it doesn't affect the functionality of my document, but it makes it more difficult to read and debug)

** PROBLEM SOLVED

I saw them in the view source as well as the inspect, and I fixed the problem (on accident), since all of my php documents require '/DBConnect.php'; and I had forgotten to clear them in my DBConnect.php file they were transitioning from there into the main HTML through the intermediary PHP file.

Thank you all for the quick feedback! If you hadn't been so quick to answer I might not have noticed that I forgot to put the DBConnect file back into the testing server after editing!

Comment: Do you see them when you view source? Just in the inspector?

Comment: I saw them in the view source, and I fixed the problem (on accident), since all of my php documents require '/DBConnect.php'; and I had forgotten to clear them in my DBConnect.php file they were transitioning from there into the main HTML through the intermediary PHP file.

Answer (score 3):

The `<meta>` and the `<title>` are injected by your browser. That's because our browser parses your html into an html document. As `<title>` is a mandatory tag in html (at least in html 4), your browser creates one for you. Some goes for the `<meta>`, though I don't think that one is mandatory (not sure.)

What you can do is right click the page and do "View page source"... You will not see the `<title>` and `<meta>` tag there. But if you right click the page and do "Inspect element", you will see them there. That's because "View page source" shows you the actual source code. And "Inspect element" shows you the rendered/parsed code.

Answer (score 1):

Just take them out of the include code.  They aren't needed.  And they really don't belong there anyway.